# StreamReader null in class

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I have got this method which creates SqlConnection string in class. I read the data from .txt file but the problém is that if there is no data inserted the app doesn't even turn on. I was wondering how can I thrown an exception in messagebox and insert that command right into this class method. I'm not sure if it is possible. Sorry if my answer is too trivial or it's non-sense. I'm not programming for long time.

```
internal static class DataSource
    {
        private static string _ConnectionString;
        public static string ConnectionString
        {
            get
            {
                if (_ConnectionString == null)
                    _ConnectionString = FunctionToDynamicallyCreateConnectionstring();
                return _ConnectionString;
            }
        }
 private static string FunctionToDynamicallyCreateConnectionstring()
        {

                string path = "C:\\Users\\marek\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\tours\\tours\\sql_string.txt";
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.Open(path, FileMode.Open));

                SqlConnectionStringBuilder cb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

                cb.DataSource = sr.ReadLine();
                cb.InitialCatalog = sr.ReadLine();
                cb.UserID = sr.ReadLine();
                cb.Password = sr.ReadLine();
                return cb.ToString();

        }
```

Comment: and whats now your problem?

Comment: @user287107 I don't know how to create command into this class for throwing an exception into MessageBox for example with "No information for connection string haven't been entered" I hope I can describe my problém properly because now I would have to do try and catch every time I have connection.Open or connection.Close command in form.

Comment: you can either use `Messagebox.Show` or `throw new ArgumentException("something");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really discourage “throwing an exception into MessageBox”, especially if that’s all you do. Exceptions are for **handling errors**, and showing a MessageBox does not handle the error. If there is nothing you can do to handle the error, stop. If you just show a message and continue you will get the same exception again when you try to use the data you didn’t get. What are you going to do then? Show another MessageBox?

What makes you think showing a MessageBox will help anyway? Will the user know how to fix it? What if the code is called from a service or background task and has no UI?

If you know how to fix the file, you should catch the exception, fix the file, and retry.

**Edit:**
OK, if you really really want to show a MessageBox “right into this class method”, try this:

```
private static string ReadConnectionstringFromFile(string path)
{
    try
    {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(File.Open(path, FileMode.Open))
        {
            var cb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            cb.DataSource = sr.ReadLine();
            cb.InitialCatalog = sr.ReadLine();
            cb.UserID = sr.ReadLine();
            cb.Password = sr.ReadLine();
            return cb.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), ex.message);
        throw new CustomExceptionClassForYourApplication("Trying to get connection string from "
            + path, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is there way to throw it into MessageBox?

Comment: This will just cause another exception down the line when he tries to instantiate a connection with a connection string full of garbage (`cb.DataSource = NonNullField(sr.ReadLine()`). This would cause ambiguity between a missing file and an actual invalid connection string. I'm not sure what this solves.

Comment: @FlyingStrudel, please try the proposals before commenting; my proposal will throw the appropriate error, distinguishing between missing file and missing contents, and forbids garbage fields. It is your proposal that does none of these; it ignores errors and can silently fill `ConnectionString` with nulls, throwing mysterious NullReferenceExceptions later when you try to use it.

Comment: @DourHighArch It doesn't ignore errors, if the file doesn't exist then `_ConnectionString` remains null forcing the next access of `ConnectionString` to check for the file again. You will never get a null connection string, you will only ever get a value or an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the access to `DataSource.ConnectionString` when your app starts up with a try/catch. Heres some pseudocode:

```
public void OnAppStart()
{
    string connString = null;
    try
    {
        connString = DataSource.ConnectionString;
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hey, the file doesn't exist!");
    }
    catch (ArgumentNullException ane)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hey, the file is missing information!");
    }
    //You should be prepared to deal with a null or malformed connString 
    //from this point forwards
}
```

Comment: I really discourage this. Nearly every .NET method, and method you will write, can throw errors; trying to wrap everything in a `try` block will quadruple the amount of code you write. And it makes your code unreliable; when `OnAppStart` exits you don't know if `DataSource.ConnectionString` is valid or not; you're hiding the error! Exceptions are for fixing errors, not for hiding them.

Comment: That assumes `DataSource.ConnectionString` is essential for the operation of the application. If the application can function without a valid connection string it should be allowed to continue operating until a valid one exists. By catching exceptions thrown from accessing the `ConnectionString` property it allows you to choose when and where to fix the error. I think you misread because I am catching the exception in `OnAppStart` not in the get of `DataSource.ConnectionString`

Comment: While I do not agree with this practice, I admit it will work and is what the questioner asked for. If you edit the question I will rescind my downvote.